# Как правильно изменить структуру

Tags: ооп, классы, php, mvc

Здравствуйте! Есть маленькая MVC система.
[image]
Это ее не полная схема, но достаточно.

К примеру в контроллере **controll_page.php**, я делаю не обходимые операции некоторым переменным присваиваю значения которое вернули мне модели.

И передаю их в шаблон.
Н-д:

```
  $subject = index::list_subject(); // Массив с предметами


  open::view("index/header");
  open::view_o("index/index",$array);
  open::view_o("index/sidebar",$subject);
  open::view("index/footer");
```

появилась проблема в том, что к примеру в почти всех контроллерах нужно передавать переменную **$subject**. Каждый раз вызвать модель будет затратно по ресурсам. Так как со временем будет расширятся. 
Извините, за фото.
Как правильно *реорганизовать* структуру?

Comment: не совсем понятно почему "в почти всех котроллерах"? у вас для формирования одной страницы используется сразу несколько контроллеров? так быть не должно

Comment: нет, 1 старица = 1 контроллер.

Comment: Представление - это отдельный уровень, в которые данные должны передаваться один раз:

    class JajaController
    {
        public function action()
        {
            $data = Model::fetchData();
            echo View::render('index', $data);
        }
    }

Что при этом происходит в методе render - контроллер не волнует. И именно там стоит разбираться, где шапка, где футер, где основное тело.

В крайнем случае можно кэшировать данные на стороне модели.

Comment: т.е сначала нужно собрать все в одном классе?

Comment: @alex159, в одном *модуле*. Реализован он через класс или как-то еще - это другой вопрос.

Comment: @Fike, реализовано оно криво. 

ООП реализовано только в моделях.

т.е обычный switch, case роутер. Который инклудит файл контроллер.
В модели производятся подсчеты, работа с бд. После чего return'om получаю эти данные и дальше работаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть паттерн/подход - не знаю как корректнее назвать: [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) . Смысл его в том, что некий объект выполняет свою наиболее ресурсоёмкую логику только тогда, когда его в первый раз запрашивают. Например в твоём случае на строчке:

```
 $subject = index::list_subject(); // Массив с предметами
```

Не должно происходить запросов в БД, а в $subject - вместо массива надо вернуть итерируемый объект. Тогда при первой итерации в методе `current` итератора - необходимо сделать этот самый запрос в БД на выбор списка.

```
protected $_list = [];
protected $_initalized = false;
public function current() {
    if (!$this->_initalized){
        $this->_list = $this->_loadSomeListFromDB();
        $this->_initalized = true;
    }
    return $this->_list[$this->position];
}
```

Но Lazy-подход плодит дополнительную логику там, где он используется. Чтобы этого избежать - вводится Lazy-контейнер. Например он называется Restore , или ServiceManager - всё Lazy инкапсулируется в контейнере. К примеру вот так мы подпихиваем в ServiceManager инициализацию подключения к БД:

```
ServiceManager::addServiceCallback('db', function() use ($dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbHost){
  return new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname=myproject', $dbUser, $dbPassword);
})
```

а затем, когда в коде вызывается в первый раз

```
$rows = ServiceManager::get('db')->query('SELECT * from FOO');
```

Сервис db инициализируется, а все последующие вызовы `ServiceManager::get('db')` будет браться уже инициализированный сервис db. Пример хорошей реализации Lazy-контейнера: [Zend 2 ServiceManager](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html)

P.S. При чём это не обязательно синглтон - пометочка, поскольку они сейчас не шибко модны.